# Is there an easier way to write a function like this to calculate the confidence interval?

Tags: r

While writing a little function to calculate the **99% confidence interval** of some sample,

I get a different answer than the **R** t.test formula.
Here's my function:

```
confinterval <- function(x,alpha){
  alpha = 0.01
  df = length(x)-1
  pos_confinterval = mean(x) + qt((1 - alpha/2),df)*(var(x)/length(x))
  neg_confinterval = mean(x) - qt((1 - alpha/2),df)*(var(x)/length(x))

  cut_points <- c(neg_confinterval,pos_confinterval)
  return(cut_points)
}
```

confinterval(data) gives me the following vector of cutpoints (4.469488 4.598704)
While :
t.test(data,conf.level=.995) yields (4.064382 5.003810)

Is there an easier way to get a function like this to calculates confidence intervals?

Comment: Changing `qt((1 - alpha/2),df)` to `qt(1 - ((1 - alpha) / 2), df)` and `(var(x)/length(x))` to `sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)-1)` should get you quite close

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to use sd() instead of var()

Comment: But qt() takes the cutpoint or percentile and here I need the qt(.995, df)  right? whereas yours  would yield: qt(0.505,df)

Comment: Your original `qt` was correct, but as @duckmayr noted you need both the standard deviation instead of the variance *and* a square root on the sample size.

Comment: When `alpha = 0.99`, then `(1 - alpha/2)` yields 0.515 due to order of operations

Comment: @duckmayr Alpha cannot be that high. "alpha refers to the likelihood that the true population parameter lies outside the confidence interval" please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, sorry. Was thinking in reference to your `t.test()` call and wanting to match up arguments as well as outputs! Just got turned around on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Aside: Do you mean to have the line `alpha = 0.01` as part of your function? I assume that 0.01 should just be passed in as a parameter value when the function is called, right?)

You're getting a different answer than `t.test` because you need a square root on the object you're multiplying by the t-distribution critical value. If you wrap `var(x) / length(x)` inside `sqrt`, you'll get the same result as `t.test`.

You can also use `as.numeric(t.test(x, conf.level = 0.99)$conf.int)` to directly access the result from the `t.test` function.

Comment: t.test(data,conf.level=.995) was one of the culprit. I had to use 0.99 instead of 0.995. Thank you !